# Nul sign when saving .tab delimited file in databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I have csv template saved on ADL. I'm reading that template and I'm appending some data from data frame and save it like tab delimited file. This is working but I have this Nul signs at the beginning and end of each row. How can I save this without these signs.
[image: Saved result with NUL sign]

Part of the code which I'm using:

```
    def saveToSingleTxt(df, saveLocation):
      txtLocation = saveLocation+'temp.folder'
      fileLocation = saveLocation

      df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").option("header", "false").option("delimiter","\t").option("quote", "\u0000").option("charset","UTF-8").mode("overwrite").save(txtLocation)

      file = dbutils.fs.ls(txtLocation)[-1].path  
      dbutils.fs.cp(file, fileLocation)
      dbutils.fs.rm(txtLocation, recurse=True)

df = getDimContent(rootPayLoadDataV)
dftempV28 = sqlContext.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "false").load(sourceADLSFullPathTemp + fileNameTempV28)
dftempV28 = dftempV28.replace('## SC\tD:YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss\tA:300092594:128', '## SC\tD:' + str(curentDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")) + '\tA:300092594:128')

df = df.withColumn("KeyContentName", concat(df["ContentID"], lit("\t"), df["ContentName"]))

appendV28 = dftempV28.union(df.select(df["KeyContentName"]))

saveToSingleTxt(df, destinationADLSFullPath + fileNameV28)
```

How can I save this without this NUL ('\x00' hexadecimal) sign?
Thanks!

Comment: Basically every row has double quotes at the beginning and end so I replaced it with unicode NUL ('quote', '\u0000'). When you open it in notepad ++ you can see this NUL, when you open it in excel there is nothing. How can I save this data from databricks without this double quotes at beginning and end of each row?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, situation is like this: When you are reading a file into data frame rows will be put into one column. Default name '_c0'. I wanted three columns for new appended file with tab delimiter. 
One way was to create schema for data frame with 3 columns and also in template file to put column names for every data that will be separated with tab delimiter.
In other data frame which I need to append to this template data frame I need to create additional column(because data frame has 2 columns) like 'lit(none)'.
Problem is when you save this appended data frame third column will be like double quotes "" what I don't want.

I decided to do it like this:

1. Create schema with one column
2. put pipeline between data which will be in separate columns in
   template file
3. read template file (will be one column)
4. replace pipeline with '\t' tab delimiter
5. append new data frame
6. save file not like tab delimited

Pay attention in appended data frame for row which consists of two columns for column/s which could have ',' sign because you are saving file like csv and also not like tab delimited. You definitely will have a problem, so replace ',' with something else.